# Using bootstrap-daterangepicker in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I'm having trouble getting bootstrap-daterangepicker to work in my vue component.

I installed the package via npm:

`npm i bootstrap-daterangepicker`

I ran `npm run dev`

I verified that the package is included in my app.js file after transpiling.

This is my vue component:

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control shawCalRanges">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">
                <span class="ti-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import moment from 'moment';
  console.log(moment().format('HH:mm'));
  import daterangepicker from 'bootstrap-daterangepicker';

  $('.shawCalRanges').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        },
        alwaysShowCalendars: true,
    });


export default {
  name: 'date-range-picker',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
}

</script>
```

I can see the time in the console from moment, but when I load the page the date picker is just a styled input box. There are no error messages in the console or anything indicating there's a problem.

**Questions:**

1. How can I get `bootstrap-daterangepicker` to work in my vue component?
2. I'm assuming this isn't the right way to structure a vue component. How would you handle this? I.e. loading a vue file with a datepicker. Is it appropriate to just stick it in the script tag? I'm new to vue and have a primarily jquery background so this is all a bit foreign to me.

Comment: Can you try moving the initialisation of the datepicker inside a vue lifecycle hook (ie created/mounted) https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram `export default { name: '...', data() { return {} }, created () { daterangepicker...  } }`

Comment: ok, putting it inside the mounted lifecycle hook seemed to do the trick. I thought I had tried all the lifecycle hooks already, but apparently I didn't get it right somehow. Now the problem is that the CSS appears to be totally screwed up...I suppose I also need to import the CSS for the daterange picker within my vue file.

Comment: Yeah just make sure the loading order of css seems to make sense, you could potentially import the datepicker css inside a scoped style tag (`<style lang="scss" scoped>`) if it's only used for that component.

Comment: got it working, thanks!